# How to compute height from lines in a QTextDocument?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to compute the bounding rect (position, size) of each line in a QTextDocument. I tried to draw the rectangle provided by each line but I'm having troubles!

Here's what I did:

```
QTextBlock currentBlock = tempDocument->begin();
while (currentBlock.isValid())
{
    const int nbLines = currentBlock.layout()->lineCount();
    for (int i(0); i < nbLines; ++i)
    {
        QTextLine currentLine = currentBlock.layout()->lineAt(i);

        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 1));
        painter->drawRect(currentLine.rect());
        painter->restore();
    }
    currentBlock = currentBlock.next();
}
```

Here's what I get: *(please see text 1 : [Text 1 - 2 - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFtLe.jpg))*

It does not really work... So I tried to do it myself with something like that:

```
float transY(tempDocument->documentMargin());
QTextBlock currentBlock = tempDocument->begin();
while (currentBlock.isValid())
{
    const int nbLines = currentBlock.layout()->lineCount();
    for (int i(0); i < nbLines; ++i)
    {
        QTextLine currentLine = currentBlock.layout()->lineAt(i);
        currentLine.setLeadingIncluded(true);

        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 1));
        painter->drawRect(QRectF(0, transY, currentLine.width(), currentLine.height()));
        painter->restore();
        transY += currentLine.height();
    }
    currentBlock = currentBlock.next();
}
```

Whenever I use a generated text from the internet which is raw I would say, this is perfect :

*(please see text 2)*

But, if I use the same text with paragraphs (< p >), the computation is totally messed up. How can I compute the space between two paragraphs ?

*(please see text 3)*

Any idea or help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

PS: sorry I would have been able to post images but I couldn't!

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792074/how-to-determine-the-rendered-height-of-the-lines-of-a-qt-document?rq=1 but it did not really help me

Comment: All links to the text images are the same?

Comment: I have only one reputation point so I can't post images and I can only post one link. The picture behind the link represents 3 texts. Each text is a different situation according to what I'm saying just above. I mentioned "please see text 1", etc.

Comment: Regarding my problem, the width of a line does not really matter, what I really need is the position and the height of each line.
I work on a text editor software with many pages (like Word) and we can use floating texts (QTextDocument). 
**I want to be able to split a QTextDocument in two if a line is clipped by a limit page, in order to have only entire lines.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it wasn't so hard after all, my mistake was to omit that **the line position is relative to its layout**. I managed to succeed obviously using `qreal QTextLine::height() const` but please note that the line position (`QPointF QTextLine::position() const`) is relative to its layout (one layout per text block). Thus, I was able to get the bounding box (`QRectF QTextLine::rect() const`) without computing it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with standard Qt API, but you can get bounding rect from private Qt class [QTextDocumentLayout](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/gui/text/qtextdocumentlayout_p.h). See next public methods:

```
virtual QRectF frameBoundingRect(QTextFrame *frame) const;
virtual QRectF blockBoundingRect(const QTextBlock &block) const;
QRectF tableBoundingRect(QTextTable *table) const;
QRectF tableCellBoundingRect(QTextTable *table, const QTextTableCell &cell) const;
```

You can include private class via adding in pro file

```
QT += gui-private
```

And including

```
#include <private/qtextdocumentlayout_p.h>
```

By default QTextDocument has QTextDocumentLayout, therefore you can cast document layout and obtain needed information:

```
QTextDocumentLayout* pDocumentLayout = qobject_cast<QTextDocumentLayout*>(textDocument.documentLayout());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the font, that is being used by a line, you can guess pretty accurately with this formula:

```
QFontMetricsF fm(document.defaultFont());
auto const height = fm.height() + fm.leading();
```

Comment: This is a rich text document with html source so it can be any mixed formatting.